# When does the system $x^n-1=y^n-1=x(y-1)^2+y(x-1)^2=0$ have only the trivial solution $(1,1)$ over the prime field of order $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, groebner-basis

Let $F_p$ be the prime field of order $p$, $\overline{F_p}$ be its algebraic closure, and $n$ be an integer such that $\gcd(n,p)=1$. Consider the following three polynomials in $F_p[x,y]$:
$$
p_1(x,y)=x^n - 1~,
\\
p_2(x,y)=y^n - 1~,
\\
p_3(x,y)=x(y-1)^2+y(x-1)^2~.
$$
It is clear that $(1,1)$ is a common zero of these polynomials, so I call this the *trivial* solution. Say $(x_0,y_0)\in\overline{F_p}^2$ is a common zero of the above system of polynomials over $\overline{F_p}$. We can generate *seven* other solutions using the following transformations:
$$
x_0 \leftrightarrow x_0^{-1}~,\qquad y_0 \leftrightarrow y_0^{-1}~,\qquad x_0 \leftrightarrow y_0~,
$$
where the first two transformations are well-defined because $n$th roots of unity are nonzero. Note that $(1,1)$ is the only solution that's invariant under these transformations.

I want to show that

> When $p>2$, there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $(1,1)$ is the **only** common zero of these polynomials over $\overline{F_p}$.

I excluded the case $p=2$ because we can always choose $x_0 = y_0$ to be any $n$th root of unity, and it would satisfy $p_3(x,y)=0$.

One way to show this would be to compute the Groebner basis of the ideal generated by the above three polynomials. In lexicographic ordering, if the Groebner basis is $(x-1,y-1)$, then $(1,1)$ is the only solution. I computed it for some small $p$ and small prime $n\ne p$ (I give some examples below), and it seems like whenever $n$ is not of the form $\frac{p^k+1}{2}$ for some integer $k$, then the Groebner basis is $(x-1,y-1)$. I don't know how to show this for all $p$, and all prime $n$ not of the form $\frac{p^k+1}{2}$.

Since the above system is zero-dimensional (because $p_1$ and $p_2$ have finite number of solutions), I thought I could instead try the characteristic set method of Wu or Ritt. I computed the characteristic sets for some small $p$ and $n$ but couldn't see any pattern that could be generalised.

Here are some examples where I restrict $n\ne p$ also to be a prime less than $100$. When $p=3$, I could show by either method that $(1,1)$ is the only common zero whenever $n\ne 41 = \frac{3^4+1}{2}$. [Note that $\frac{3^3+1}{2}=14$ is not a prime, and $\frac{3^2+1}{2}=5$ and $\frac{3^1+1}{2}=2$ are small enough that the Groebner basis is still $(x-1,y-1)$.] Similarly, when $p=5$, $n\ne 13 = \frac{5^2+1}{2}$, and when $p=11$, $n\ne 61 = \frac{11^2+1}{2}$.

I would really appreciate any approaches that would prove/disprove the above statement for any $p$, or even for some fixed small $p$, say $p=3$.

Comment: I think that if $n>5$ is a prime such that $p$ mod $n$ is a generator (iirc there are conjecturally infinitely many of them but even for $p=2$ it’s open), then any solution $(x,y)$ is (up to the transformations you highlighted) of the form $(x,x^l)$ with $0<l< (n-1)/2$ and $x$ is a root of $\Phi_n$ (irreducible) and $(X^l-1)^2X+(X-1)^2X^l$ (nonzero of lower degree). If moreover $n^2$ does not divide $p^{n-1}-1$, then any power of this $n$ should also work.

Comment: @Mindlack That's wonderful! Thanks a lot for your comment. I have a few questions. I can see why $l>0$ but I don't see why $l<(n-1)/2$. Even if $l\le(n-1)/2$, note that $p_3(X,X^l) = X(X-1)^2 f(X)$, where $\deg f = 2l-2 \le n-3 < n-1 = \deg \Phi_n$. If I understand you correctly, since $\deg f < \deg \Phi_n$ and $\Phi_n(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$, there is no such $x$, am I right? Also, I see that if $p^{n-1} \not\equiv 1 \mod n^2$, then $p$ is a primitive root of $n^k$ for any $k\ge 2$,  but I don't see why every root is of the form $(x,x^l)$. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I agree with the first part of your comment – I was trying to find minimal conditions so that “things worked”. Anyway, if $y=x^{(n-1)/2}$, then $x=(y^{-1})^2$ so we can choose $(y^{-1},x)$ as a solution instead – but your argument is better. For the last part, if $(x,y)$ is a solution, up to switching we can assume that the order of $y$ divides that of $x$ (because both orders are powers of the prime $n$), and thus $y$ is a power of $x$.

Comment: That's a neat trick! Thanks for explaining why the roots are still of the form $(x,x^l)$. Suppose $x$ has order $n^r$ for some $1\le r\le k$. Then $x$ is a root of $\Phi_{n^r}(X)$, which has degree $n^r-n^{r-1}$. I don't yet see why $l\le(n^r-n^{r-1})/2$ for $r>1$ (I see that it works the same way as before for $r=1$). Using your trick, I tried some small examples and convinced myself that $r=2$ works. I am not sure how $r=3$ works though. For example, say $n=5$, $r=3$, and $l=60>50=\frac{5^3-5^2}{2}$. I don't see how to use the transformations to make $l$ smaller than 50.

Comment: If $y=x^l$ with $n > l \geq n/2$, then $y^{-1}=x^{n-l}$ with $n/2 \geq n-l > 0$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I’m missing something. Why is $y^{-1}=x^{n-l}$? In my last comment $x^{n^r}=1$, but $x^n \ne 1$. In particular, for $n=5$, $r=3$ and $y= x^{60}$, I get $y^{-1}=x^{65}$. I don’t see how I can get an $l$ smaller than $50$. In general, I get $l\le(n^r-1)/2$ instead of $l\le(n^r-n^{r-1})/2$. Can you please explain? Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Oops, you’re right. I rushed too much… my argument doesn’t work at all.

Comment: No problem! The first part of your first comment which uses the [Artin’s conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) is good enough for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I knew about that conjecture, but I didn’t realize until today how close to “proven” it actually was! I guess it’s more helpful than I expected.

Comment: @Mindlack That's right, it's very helpful. BTW, I just made a small observation. Consider the example above, with $n=5$, $r=3$, and let $\omega$ be the primitive 125th root of unity. Say $(x,y)=(\omega,\omega^{60})$. I can write $(x,y)=(z^{21},z^{10})$, where $z=\omega^6$ is also a primitive 125th root of unity. So $z$ is a root of $\Phi_{5^3}(X)$ and $p_3(X^{21},X^{10})$ but the latter has smaller degree. Essentially, this is a small tweak in your argument but I think this will generalize to all powers of $n$. What do you think?

Comment: That’s a very good idea! If $(x,y)=(z^s,z^t)$ then the polynomial has degree $s+t+\max(s,t)$. The problematic case is the solution $(x,x^l)$ with $(n^{k}-n^{k-1})/2 \leq l \leq n^k/2$. But if $x=z^2$ with $z$ a $n^k$-th root of unity, then $y^{-1}=z^{n^k-2l}$ with $n^k-2l \leq n^{k-1} < (n^k-n^{k-1})/2$ – in fact for $n$ not too small $2(n^k-2l)+2+2$ will be smaller than $n^k-n^{k-1}$ and we can get our conclusion… I wonder if this trick cabln also be used to loosen the restriction on the prime $n$?

Comment: That's fantastic! It completely answers my question for $p=3$ because it is a primitive root modulo all powers of $n=5,7$. Thanks so much! If $n$ is not prime, there are no primitive roots modulo $n^k$ for any $k\ge1$, right? What do you have in mind for loosening this restriction?

Comment: I meant trying to find primes $n$ such that $p$ has large order mod $n$, but doesn’t need to be a generator (say, it has order at least $cn^{1-\epsilon}$ – it’s still a huge improvement). For any integer $n \geq 2$, the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic iff $n$ is $2,4$, a power of an odd prime or twice a power of an odd prime.

Comment: That makes sense. For my purposes, whatever we have so far is more than sufficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136279/discussion-between-pranay-and-mindlack).

Comment: *Sigh* chat doesn’t want this. Your idea gives a better result. If $n$ is prime, $N^2>n$ and $0 < l <n$, there are $0< s,t \leq N$ such that $t= \pm ls$ mod $n$. Indeed, the $r_s=ls\text { mod }n$ for $1 \leq s \leq N$ are $N$ numbers between $1$ and $n$ so there are $0<a<b\leq N$ with $|r_a-r_b|\leq N$. So take $s=(b-a)$, $t=(\pm ls)\text{ mod }n$. So if $(x,x^l)$ is a solution, then we can write $(x,x^l)=(z^s,z^t)$ and the polynomial equation in $z$ has degree at most $3N$. So *if the order of $p$ mod $n$ is more than $3N$ then there still are no nontrivial solutions for $n$*. (Cont’d)

Comment: Something along those lines might also work for prime powers (assuming perhaps that $n^2$ does not divide $p^{n-1}-1$ to get a good bound on the orders – but the issue that not every $s$ is suitable comes up and the computation might be more complicated).

Comment: This is really great! Glad that my idea helped. I need some more time to think about how to extend to prime powers.